# Execute server-side callback after res.render();

Tags: express

I'm rendering an index page with Express.js.

```
 res.render('home/index', {
                    languages: home.languages,
                    users: home.users,
                    language: res.locals.language,
                    currentUser: user
 });
```

I want to then execute some more server-side code after this. I tried `res.render` with a callback but of course discovered that this doesn't send the rendered html to the client (from the Express docs):

```
res.render('user', { name: 'Tobi' }, function(err, html){
  // ...
});
```

I'm new to the web platform and the only thing I could think of was to `res.render`, and then on client-side, on something like `window.onload`, call the callback there. But it seems like I should be able to complete this loop server-side without having to go through the client.

Comment: What do you mean by "after"? Just put more code on the next line.

Comment: The code I want to execute next acts on the rendered client-side html, so I want to make sure it's rendered, sent to the client, and loaded.

Comment: Then you need to put it in the view.  You can't run server-side code on the client.